# ASP.NET Web API: Design Practices for Clients

Tags: asp.net-web-api, client

For people who follow the fairly new `ASP.NET Web API`, they know that it is a good framework for building well-designed and outwardly-facing HTTP services that can span across many different clients using standard XML or JSON content types.

I have been recently designing a large API to be used with both a web and mobile clients. I noticed that within the ASP.NET Web API template provided through Microsoft's `NuGet` packages for Web API, they take a very minimal approach into Views with a slightly pretty homepage.

This took me back in a way. Mainly because I would assume that the Web API is designed for exactly that, a Web API, and nothing else.

In other's opinions, is it standard to develop the web client (that interfaces with your API)

- Inside the Web API project?

  **Or**
- Outside the Web API Project to separate the web client just as you would your mobile or desktop clients?

The second choice seems logical to me in ways of maintainability and code-cleanliness, but there may be other perspectives that could be beneficial when designing in ASP.NET Web API. What do you think?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/alisabzevari/LiteApi. It helps you get the idea of how to design apis properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great to see you using Web API!

About your first issue, you're right that it conceptually makes sense to separate Web APIs from views. I'd recommend either using the "Empty" project type in the MVC new project dialog and then adding API controllers. Or adding the NuGet packages yourself to an empty web project. The packages shouldn't be adding any views to your project.

Concerning clients, I'd strongly recommend separating out a client library to a separate project for maintainability. It's fine to have common data types that you share between the client and the Web API though. In that case, it's a common pattern to move your models to a separate dll, and have both the client and the Web API reference the types in that library.

A couple reasons you'd want the client and the Web API to be separate (and there are many more):

- If you distribute the library, you want to distribute the client code and not the Web API code
- You want to create a clean contract between the client and the server and avoid having the client depend on the server implementation or vice versa.

Comment: Youssef,
Could you provide a sample of the design pattern you mentioned?  Is it possible to build a default client interface (view or presentation layer) in a separate project and distributed as a view DLL?  So that all users can use without building customized views?